# How can I stop the workflow with the bookmark code? in which part?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, bookmarks

I'm using the WF, and I've wrote a bookmark with the following code:

```
    [RequiredArgument]
    public OutArgument<int> out_ar { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {

        context.CreateBookmark("samename", new BookmarkCallback(OnBookmarkCallback));

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    void OnBookmarkCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object val)
    {
        out_ar.Set(context, (int)val);
        int no = (int)val;

    }
}
```

}

My question is, when I can tast the Val argument if it's not as what I want, i want to stop the workflow till the right value come then I can resume the workflow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `context.CreateBookmark()` add a `BookmarkOptions.MultipleResume` option and in the `OnBookmarkCallback()` call `context.RemoveBookmark(bookmark)` if you are satisfied with the value received.

Comment: if I write if ( val == true ) context.RemoveBookmark(bookmark); so it wont remove the bookmark and it will still idel ?? thank you

Comment: Yes, it will go back to an idle state untill the bookmark is resumed again.

Comment: how can I resume it again?? i need it to check the value till it be true. if there is no way for that, do i have to replace the if in while loop?

Comment: Remove the bookmark and the workflow continues with the next step. Leave it in place and the workflow stays put. It really is that simple :-)

Comment: I noticed it calls the resumebookmark before the createbookmark, how could it be?